# Settings.Default value does not change after release

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows forms desktop application. I am using a settings variable in resource named `Settings.Default.Code`

So I set the value initial value in `Form->Properties->Settings.Code="123"`

And I have changed the value in application using code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Settings.Default.Code = "ABC";
   Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

After button click the Code value is same as following image

[image]:

But if I get the value in code Settings.Default.Code is "ABC"

When I created a setup project and release the application, the value of this settings should be "123" but it is "ABC". The initial value is not get from first setted value. Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the block of code in your application where you change the value?

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: If you manually set the Code to 123 in the Project Properties, then run the application, click the button1 and close the application, can you check what is the current Code value in the Project Properties file ?

Comment: Yes I check and update post with an image. The file value does not change. But if I get the value in code `Settings.Default.Code` is "ABC"

Comment: Your question is unclear. But if I understand correctly, you are saying that when you "release the application" (i.e. install it to some other location), the test value you set while running the program has somehow become preserved, rather than using the default. This sounds normal to me, assuming the "other location" is on the same machine, running as the same user. As long as you still get the default value when the program is run by a different user, that sounds fine to me.

Comment: @RafaelDuarte: I have rolled back your edit. While the question is not clear and your attempt to improve that situation is admirable, your edit radically changed the actual meaning of what had originally been written, and should never have been approved. Please review the guidance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work. Note that while _clarification_ is good, you must not _change the meaning_ of the post, which you did here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the beginning of your program:

```
Settings.Default.Reset();
```

More info: [ApplicationSettingsBase.Reset Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: But begin runs both when I run for debugging and after release. So every time will run it.

Comment: You don't want it to run every time ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Duniho mentioned, the problem is probably that the setting is already saved to your profile on your computer. Try to delete the config file before you test again:

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\{ApplicationName}

or

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\{ApplicationName}